# Drawing with depth to a bitmap

Tags: flash, bitmap, xna, haxe, openfl

Lately I have been using haxe and openfl to (attempt) to make games, I'm coming from previous knowledge with XNA, where, when drawing with a spritebatch, you can specify a depth to draw the image, independent of when you actually call the draw function. starting out with openfl, I noticed that drawing to a bitmapdata as a buffer provided me with a similar way to draw as a spritebatch, but it does not have a depth parameter.

My question is, does anyone know of a good way of handling draw calls to allow for specifying a draw depth?

Answer (score 0):

Depth buffer is not enabled in `openfl` so you have to fallback to another render path ( ie engine).

Otherwise you can patch `openfl` to fetch depth buffer and implement `z-test` but it requires lot of knowledge.

Comment: I was using an array of "DrawCall" objects to sort by depth (I used a string identifier for the image, so as to save memory), and then looping through the array to draw in order to the screen, but if I drew more than 10 sprites, it locked up completly, which is not usable in any way

Answer (score 0):

You can set the depth by creating new bitmap for each depth you need, then you can change the depth of each created bitmap.

This is handled in openfl, but you can also see how haxeflixel handles depth of created elements..

Comment: isnt that only if you are using a displaylist?

Comment: Yes, in case you don't use displaylist you will have to clear buffer each time logical depth changes and draw all elements again..